# Question about Double Pulley (Challenge Problem in Book)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I worked out formulas for the tension in the ropes and acceleration of the masses for the situation presented below. I was then given specific numbers such that $m_{1}+m_2=m_3$. After plugging these numbers into the formulas, I found, contrary to my intuition, that $m_3$ still experiences acceleration. I already worked out and confirmed the formulas/math. Can someone please explain the intuition behind the result using Netwon's laws? Are there perhaps limiting cases that may make the situation clearer? Also, how should I make sense of this formula?

Also $T_A=\frac {4g}{4/m_3+1/m_1+1/m_2} $

$T_B=2T_A $
[image]

Comment: Why is this problem off topic? He obviously worked out the expressions, and he's just asking for an intuitive interpretation of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where $m_1=m_2=\frac{m_3}{2}$. If you work out the equations, you should find that $m_3$, in fact, does not accelerate. This is because the two masses remain stationary relative to each other, so the entire gravitational force is not "used" by $m_1$ or $m_2$, and instead "transmitted" to the tension of the string connecting $m_1$ and $m_2$, balancing out the weight of $m_3$.

Now, you can consider the case where $m_1\gg m_2$. In this case, the string connecting $m_1$ and $m_2$ will obviously "slip", and it would be as if $m_1$ is free falling without anything "holding it back". In this case, the gravitational force will be fully "used" by $m_1$, and none of it will be transmitted to the string connecting $m_1$ and $m_2$. Therefore, $m_3$ will experience near free-fall, since there is no tension to balance it.

Comment: Since tension in rope associated with b=2*tension in the rope of A, for balance I think we'd need m1=m2=m3/2. The second part made sense, though.

Comment: That is correct. What is your question though?

Comment: I added in the formulas. Can you consider the role of m_3, which affects the tension?

Comment: In your formula, you can see that the tension increases with $m_3$. This makes sense because if $m_3$ is heavy, then you would have a greater upward acceleration on pulley A, along with $m_1$ and $m_2$. Therefore, you would need a greater tension in string A to "pull" the two masses. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you plug $m_1=m_2=\frac{m_3}{2}$ into the formula, you get $T_A=m_1g$, so $T_B=2T_A=2m_1g=m_3g$, balancing out the gravitational force of $m_3$, so $m_3$ shouldn't accelerate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming m1>>m2. As m1 is able to fall, gravity is accerating it, rather than being transmitted to massless pulley A.

When you drop an object, even if it it is tied to a string you are holding, its weight does not act on you.